# Function called on componentDidMount instead onClick

Tags: reactjs

I'm making function for resetting password. 
Function `resetPassword` in defined in one Component but it's called using `props` in other Component which is making callback with arguments given from `state`.

This is first component where resetPassword is defined and send as a props parameter to component User.

```
resetPassword(password, confirmPass){
   alert(passsword + " " confirmPass);
}

render() {
    return (
        <User resetPassword={this.resetPassword} />
    )
  }
```

Component User is calling that functions by giving arguments from state.

```
<button onClick={this.props.resetPassword(this.state.password, this.state.confirmPass)} className="btn" data-toggle="button">Change password</button>
```

The problem is that function is calling when the first component is unmounted instead onClick as it defined.

Any ideas?

Comment: use onClick={() => this.props.resetPassword(this.state.password, this.state.confirmPass) }

Comment: Yes that works. I didn't noticed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trying to call function in onClick handler instead of binding it.

Try this:

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.resetPassword(this.state.password, this.state.confirmPass)} className="btn" data-toggle="button">Change password</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your calling the function when you making the button you have a few options

```
<button onClick={this.props.resetPassword(this.state.password, this.state.confirmPass)} className="btn" data-toggle="button">Change password</button>
```

below are the ways you can bind the values without calling the function.

```
onClick={this.props.resetPassword.bind(this,this.state.password, this.state.confirmPass)
onClick={() => this.props.resetPassword(this.state.password, this.state.confirmPass) }
```